# Error: schemaLocation does not contain namespace-location pairs

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm really new to creating XML based from an XSD. I could not find any answers the correct syntax for namespace, hoping I could get some help here.

The declaration of namespaces seems to be **valid** in Stylus:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:Magic xpa.printdata" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           targetNamespace="urn:Magic xpa.printdata">
<xs:element name="projectnr">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:totalDigits value="6"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

**Is `"urn:Magic xpa.printdata"` a valid namespace value?**

After I validated the XML from the XSD I got an error:

> schemaLocation does not contain namespace-location pairs

The first pair of schemalocation has a whitespace in between the texts "Magic xpa.prindata". What is the correct syntax? I tried removing the space and it validated my XML, but the generated XSD should not be changed. My employer doesn't want me to change or remove any character in the provided XSD. Please let me know I missed some namespaces that needs to be included in my XML.

Answer (score 2):

Namespace names may ***not*** contain unescaped spaces because they are URIs,

> ### [2.1 Basic Concepts](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#concepts)
>
> [Definition: An **XML namespace** is identified by a URI reference
>   [[RFC3986]](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt); element and attribute names may be placed in an XML
>   namespace using the mechanisms described in this specification. ]

and URIs cannot contain unescaped spaces.  If you want to embed a space in the namespace, you'll have to use URL encoding for a space (`%20`), and you'll have to change the XSD.  The following XML and XSD show how:

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectnr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="urn:Magic%20xpa.printdata try.xsd">123456</projectnr>
```

### XSD

```
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:Magic%20xpa.printdata" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           targetNamespace="urn:Magic%20xpa.printdata">
  <xs:element name="projectnr">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:totalDigits value="6"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```